# LINQ sorting: Cannot order by type 'System.IComparable'

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, sql-order-by, expression

I'm building a small search class that uses predicatebuilder to get some results:

here is my query:

```
var results = (from u in db.users
               join p in db.profiles on u.userId equals p.UserID
               select new SearchResult { Profile = p, User = u }).AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
```

Results become an enumerable of SearchResult:

```
public class SearchResult 
{
    public user User { get; set; }
    public profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine but now I also want to sort it:

```
var sortedResult = results.OrderBy(x => x.User.timeAdded);
```

And this works fine too except when I do:

```
Expression<Func<SearchResult, IComparable>> OrderByExpression = x => x.User.timeAdded;
var sortedResult = results.OrderBy(OrderByExpression);
```

I get this error: Cannot order by type 'System.IComparable'.

Isn't this exactly the same as putting the lambda query right into the orderby clause (which works) ? The reason why I doing this is that I want to pass the orderby expression to another function.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please, show the implementation of OrderByExpression

Answer (score 1):

`OrderBy` expects an expression of type `Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>>`. In your code, `TSource` is `SearchResult` and `TResult` is `IComparable`, which can't be translated to a DB query. You want `TResult` to be a primitive type equals to the concrete type of `timeAdded`, (given the name, I assume it's a `DateTime`?) for this to work.

```
Expression<Func<SearchResult, DateTime>> OrderByExpression = x => x.User.timeAdded;
var sortedResult = results.OrderBy(OrderByExpression);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (no access to VS right now, so it's more of a guess):

```
Func<SearchResult, IComparable> OrderByFunc = x => x.User.timeAdded;
var sortedResult = results.OrderBy(OrderByFunc);
```